# Solving 12! but for addition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve the equivalent of 12! but rather than have 12 * 11 * 10 * n...I'm trying to figure out how to write this equation in terms of addition, so 12 + 11 + 10..etc.  Any ideas on how to write that?

Comment: So you are trying to write $1+2+\ldots+11+12$?

Comment: I think the OP wants to find a closed form of $12!$ using a linear combination of the constants $1$ to $12$, which is not fruitful at all.

Comment: Need to clarify what OP is asking. It could be a notation for $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} k = \frac{n (n + 1)}{2}$ like $n! = \prod_{1 \le k \le n} k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\large \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is the equation that solves this

Comment: Um, there's no equals sign there, so it cannot be an equation. It's just an expression (or foruma).

Answer (score 3):

For every $n \in \mathbb{N},$ $$n+ (n-1) + \ldots 2 + 1 \;= \;1+2+\ldots+ (n-1) +n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

So for $n = 12,\;$ just compute $\;\dfrac{12(12+1)}2$

**Challenge:** See if you can prove this by induction on $n$.

Comment: Is this the question you were asking: the sum of numbers 1 to n, rather than the product of numbers 1 to n?

Comment: I don't think it is like a challenge. +1

Answer (score 2):

Add:

$$\begin{array}{c}
1&+&2&+&3&+&\ldots&+&(n-1)&+&n&=&S\\
n&+&(n-1)&+&(n-2)&+&\ldots&+&2&+&1&=&S\\ \hline
(n+1)&+&(n+1)&+&(n+1)&+&\ldots&+&(n+1)&+&(n+1)&=&2S
\end{array}$$

There are $n$ columns, so the bottom line is $n(n+1)=2S$, and therefore $S=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$.

Comment: Nice "proof"! +1

Comment: @amWhy: It’s one of the two quasi-pictorial arguments that I used to use in liberal arts math classes. The other is to observe that $\sum_{k=1}^nk$ is half the number of cells that are left in an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ array after you throw out the diagonal. This was an especially useful way to look at it when talking about the number of head-to-head comparisons necessary to carry out the Condorcet electoral method, or the number of edges in $K_n$.

Comment: they really "hit home", intuitively!